# PowerShell exit event does not work when referencing function

Tags: powershell

I have a `.ps1` script that needs some code to execute for cleanup purposes once the PowerShell session ends. Simplest reproduction of the problem I am having:

```
function ExitLogic(){
     Write-Host 'closing'
}
Write-Host 'started'
Register-EngineEvent `
    -SourceIdentifier ([System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent]::Exiting) `
    -Action { ExitLogic }
```

The ExitLogic never happens. Not if I manually use the `exit` command within my PowerShell session, not if I click the `X` window button, not if I run PowerShell within a `cmd.exe`... I'm at a loss. *But*, if I change the `Action` parameter from referencing `ExitLogic` as a function to just `Write-Host 'inline closing'` then it does work.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Finally {}` block?

Comment: Write-Host is not a good evidence. Use `[System.Console]::Beep()`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I didn't include this detail, but my use case is eventually in a module. Need something automatic when things are getting closed out.

Comment: @Reza thanks for that suggestion! I forget about console beeps. That would be much easier for detecting it, I was resorting to launching PowerShell via a CMD prompt where I could then `exit` without the original window closing and I would be able to see text written to host.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Depending on how your script is invoked, the `-Action` script block may not see your `ExitLogic` function - to ensure that it is visible there, define the function in the *global* scope.

---

**General points:**

- **`*.ps1` files do NOT run in a child *process***, so exiting the *script* is NOT tantamount to exiting the PowerShell *engine* as a whole.
- **scripts by default run in a child *scope***, so functions defined therein are only in scope while the script is running.
- **Only functions defined in the *global* scope can be referenced in an `-Action` script block**, because it runs in a *dynamic module* (an in-memory module, which, like persisted [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), sees only definitions from the global scope).
- **By the time the `-Action` script block executes, much of regular PowerShell functionality is no longer available**.<sup>Written as of v6.2.0</sup>

  - Notably, PowerShell's own **output streams cannot be used anymore** - regular output and error messages no longer print.
  - However, you *can* **use `Write-Host` to produce *display* output** (though an outside caller *will* receive that via stdout), but note that **if the engine exiting also closes the current console window, you won't even get to see that.** A `Read-Host` command can delay the closing.
  - It seems that only commands from the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` module are available, whereas all other modules have already been unloaded - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000).
- **Important**: The **event handler only gets to run *if PowerShell itself exits the session*** (whether normally or via a script-terminating error triggered with `throw`) - **if you terminate PowerShell *indirectly* by *closing the console / terminal window*, the event handler won't run** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70497925/45375) for details.

**Your specific case**:

- ***Unless* you happen to call your script file via the  `-File` parameter (as opposed to `-Command`) of the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)** (`powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell, `pwsh` for PowerShell (Core) 7+), **the `-Action` script block does *not* see the `ExitLogic` function**, because it is then only defined in the *script file*'s scope, not the global one.

  - One way to make `ExitLogic` available in the *global* scope is to "dot-source" your script (e.g., `. .\script.ps1`), but note that only works *from* the global scope (this is essentially what the `-File` CLI parameter does - it dot-sources the script file in the global scope); more work is needed to add a function to the global scope from a child scope or module scope.

The following snippet demonstrates this:

Let's assume the existence of script `.\script.ps1` with the following content:

```sh
function ExitLogic {
  Write-Host 'closing'
}

Write-Host 'started'

$null = Register-EngineEvent `
 -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting `
 -Action { 
   try { ExitLogic } catch { Write-Host $_ }
   Read-Host -Prompt 'Press ENTER to exit' 
 }
```

<sup>Note: As [`Get-Help Register-EngineEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent?view=powershell-5.1) states, the following `-SourceIdentifier` values are supported: `PowerShell.Exiting`, `PowerShell.OnIdle`, and `PowerShell.OnScriptBlockInvoke`, which correspond to the value of the enum-*like* [`[System.Management.Automation.PSEngineEvent]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psengineevent?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0); using the latter explicitly (as in the OP) gives you more type safety, but is also more cumbersome to type.</sup>

**Caveat**: **The following sample commands exit the running PowerShell session**; it is only the `Read-Host` command that keeps the window open, allowing you to inspect the event handler's `Write-Host` output; on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the window *closes*.

- Direct invocation (the equivalent of `powershell.exe -Command "& .\script.ps1 ..."` from the outside):

```sh
# Due to direct invocation, the -Action block does NOT see ExitLogic()
PS> .\script.ps1; exit
started
The term 'ExitLogic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Press ENTER to exit:
```

- Dot-Sourced invocation (the equivalent of calling `powershell.exe -File script.ps1 ...` from the outside):

```sh
# Thanks to dot-sourcing in the global scope, the -Action block DOES see ExitLogic()
PS> . .\script.ps1; exit
started
closing
Press ENTER to exit:
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! Now I need to figure out the implications of this within a module... That's where all of this stemmed from. I'm trying to integrate a .net logging library and have my module running a `.ps1` file as part of module initialization that sets up the logging and then after any processing that utilizes the module completes I need to close and flush the logging. Perhaps the dot sourcing will work here, or the global option.

Comment: @Ethan: Glad to hear it was helpful. Unfortunately, dot-sourcing only loads into the _current_ scope, so if you dot-source from within a module, the resulting definitions will _not_ be in the global scope (I've updated the answer to make that clearer). You can either explicitly create a duplicate of the on-exit function in the global scope or pass its body (script block) directly to `-Action` (assuming no further dependencies on custom functions). If you're having difficulty with this, I suggest you ask a _new_ question.