# Powershell - Changing X-button behavior of console

Tags: powershell, com, event-handling, exit

I am working with a script that uses Excel as a COM application, so whenever I close my scipt using the X-button, it will leave an Excel task open in the background.

So I have a function that will close the Exceltask whenever I give "exit" as an user input, but I want to be able to close the **console** and excel with the X-button in the console. Is there any way that I can change the behavior from the X-button so it will first trigger a function, maybe? To give an idea about the function:

```
function Close(){   
    if($workbook){$workbook.close($false)}
    if($excel){[void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)}
    [gc]::Collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Remove-Variable excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    exit
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems that exiting via the x-button will remain an issue for me as this [thread (github)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000) suggests.

So the reason for whom it interests is [that](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000#issuecomment-476875706):

> "The event *never* kicks in if PowerShell is not in control of its own termination: Thus, closing the window / quitting the terminal emulator will not run the event handler."

which is just what so happens by pressing the x-button. So this issue is being considered in PS 7.0. Furthermore [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476484/powershell-exit-event-does-not-work-when-referencing-function), which discusses the same problem, also helped me find the thread on github.

Answer (score 1):

You can carry out events when the form closes:

```
$form.Add_FormClosing({
    # Actions to carry out when form closed.
})
```

Edit:

$Null supresses output - you can remove it to see whats going on.

The following code works on my PC:

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action { New-Item -Path c:\temp -Name text.txt }
```

File created when PS window shut

Comment: Im sorry, i was'nt talking about forms in Powershell. I meant the X-button in the _host_ window.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It look like this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8429920/6203113

Comment: So the only thing i can do is replace events triggered by the `exit` command? Bummer.

Comment: No - look at the comments, the Exit event is triggered by the X button which closes the window as of PS v3

Comment: Okay, so i've tryed this: `$null = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier
     ([System.Management.Automation.PsEngineEvent]::Exiting) -Action { echo hi }`, but it does'nt seem to work. I tryed it in my script and in a powershell window but i honestly dont even know what `$null` is doing there

Comment: See my edited post above - this works on my PC, creates the file when I close the PS window.

Comment: This didnt do it either :/ I pasted the command into my PS and closed the window through `exit` and by pressing X. In both cases i didnt find _C:\temp\text.txt_. Am I missing anything? I also tried changing the path to _$:env:userprofile\desktop_ but nothing either... :/