# Automatically call a function when the PowerShell script window closes the X button

Tags: powershell

I want my powershell script to call a specific function when the script is closed from the close window button (X).

Would this be possible?

I will share my try:

`Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action {FunctionName}`

But it doesn't work at all. (doesn't call the function when I close the window from 'X')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **due to a *long-standing bug*** - see [GitHub issue #8000](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000#issuecomment-542412046) - **the `PowerShell.Exiting` event does *not* fire when the session is exited *by closing the console window* as of PowerShell 7.1** (as opposed to PowerShell itself exiting the session, such as via `exit`).

Two asides:

- Even when the event does fire, `-Action { FunctionName }` will only work if the function is defined in the *global* scope (or inside the `-Action` script block itself, before invocation), because the script block runs in a *dynamic module*.
- The script block executes at a time when all PowerShell modules except `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` have already been unloaded, which severely limits what operations you can perform.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479997/45375) for more information.